# Printing formatted array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I'm trying to print out an 2D-array by traversing through it with a nested for-loop within a for-loop.

```
char[][] largeArray = {{'&','&','^','#','@','@','@','@','&','*','*','*'},
                       {'#','&','&','^','@','@','@','@','*','*','*','*'}}

for (int r = 0; r < 2; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 12; c++)
    {
        System.out.print(largeArray[r][c]);
    }
}
```

What it prints out is a single line of everything within that array

is there a way to print the first line of that array( everything in the first bracket)
then the next line or next bracket? I don't want any extra space between the first line and the second line. so I can't really just use `System.out.println();`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to print a newline after printing each rows:

```
for(int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < 12; c++)
    {
        System.out.print(largeArray[r][c]);
    }
    System.out.println(); // Add this outside the inner loop
}
```

---

You can also consider using `Arrays.toString` method to print your array, to avoid using nested loops like this:

```
for(int r = 0; r < 2; r++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(largeArray[r]));
}
```

---

Also, in order to further make your code look good, you can use an enhanced for-loop, instead of the old loop, to avoid indexing the array like this:

```
for (char[] arr: largeArray) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: that certainly did the trick, thanks for the quick response. will accept answer when it lets me